# Why does a compact, connected surface have a representation as a quotient in a polygon?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

I studied the classification theorem for compact and connected surfaces a few years ago. The proof that I was told and that is presented in many books uses representations of quotients of polygons. I sketch it in the following paragraph.

Essentially, you begin with an arbitrary polygon with some quotients between its sides (which represents a compact and connected surface) and you show that the representation is homeomorphic to another one of a sum of tori and projective planes (or homeomorphic to a sphere). Finally, you show that a sum of tori and projective planes is homeomorphic to another one if both are orientable (or both are not orientable) and they have the same Euler characteristic.

I am interested in the two first lines of the previous paragraph, that is, "If I am given an arbitrary connected, compact surface why can I assume that it is homeomorphic to a polygon with some quotients between some sides?". Another formulation of the same question is " Why has a compact, connected surface a representation as a quotient in a polygon?". It seems to me that it is the property of being compact what ensures that you can do this, but I can not see clearly why.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Definitely you need to assume compactness, since any quotient of a polygon is a compact space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *triangulation theorem for surfaces*. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17578/triangulating-surfaces) for a discussion.

Comment: That is definitely what I was looking for. Thank you very much.